# zstd compressobj() not working in python 0.8.1?

Tags: compression, zstandard

Still very new to use this python module, zstd 0.8.1. I did a test run on the following,

```
import zstd

cctx = zstd.ZstdCompressor()
zstd_data = cctx.compress(b'aaaaa')
len(zstd_data)
Out[34]: 14  #this is my output
```

However when i did,

```
cobj = cctx.compressobj()
zstd_data = cobj.compress(b'aaaaa')
len(zstd_data)
Out[39]: 0  #why the length is 0?
```

What is my mistakes?

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been a while, but figured I'd answer for anybody that sees this page on Google.

It looks like you're using the `python-zstandard` library (https://github.com/indygreg/python-zstandard/issues). It is important to note that in the examples, the last line for the ZstdCompressor object demos use `zstd_data = cobj.flush()`. After you add that line, it should work.

Or, if you prefer the [simple API](https://github.com/indygreg/python-zstandard#simple-api):

```
cctx = zstd.ZstdCompressor()
compressed = cctx.compress(b'data to compress')
```

Your second example did not include the `flush()` step, which is required for `compressobj()`